Error consuming purchase with token. Response code: 6 - Google Play Billing Android Java
So, recently I've been using android billing In-app purchases in my app. This is my first time for this and I wanted to implement Consumable Purchase. But after too much reasearch also, I couldn't find the issue.
Whatever I try, I keep getting
This is my java code:
Error consuming purchase with token. Response code: 6
Error consuming purchase!
Please try to reply as soon as possible if you know.
Thanks in advance.
Update: I'm removing unwanted code as per comments.

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;



public class PurchaseCoins extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BillingClient billingClient;
    private Purchase currentPurchase; // Add this line
    private static final String TAG = "PurchaseCoins";

    
    private BillingResult billingResult175;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase_coins);
        



        // Initialize billingClient
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(PurchaseCoins.this)
                .setListener(purchasesUpdatedListener)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build();


        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Billing client setup finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                // Handle billing client setup failure
                Log.e(TAG, "Billing client setup failed with response code: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Some Unknown error occurred! Please contact us if repeated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                billingClient.startConnection(this);
            }
        });

        

        Button buy100 = findViewById(R.id.buy100);
        Button buy500 = findViewById(R.id.buy500);
        Button buy1000 = findViewById(R.id.buy1000);
        Button buy2000 = findViewById(R.id.buy2000);
        Button buy5000 = findViewById(R.id.buy5000);
        Button buy10000 = findViewById(R.id.buy10000);
        Button buy10000000 = findViewById(R.id.buy10000000);
        Button buy10000000000 = findViewById(R.id.buy10000000000);





        buy100.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy1000");
        });
        buy500.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy5000");
        });
        buy1000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy10000");
        });
        buy2000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy20000");
        });

        buy5000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy50000");
        });

        buy10000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy100000");
        });
        buy10000000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy10000000");
        });
        buy10000000000.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            purchaseCoinsListener("buy10000000000");
        });


    }


    private PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
            // To be implemented in a later section.
            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK
                    && purchases != null) {
                for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                    currentPurchase = purchase;
                    handlePurchase(purchase);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated: Called handlePurchase" );
                }
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Already Owned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
             else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_UNAVAILABLE) {
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Item Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                 Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
            } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_TIMEOUT) {
                 Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
            } else {
                // Handle any other error codes.
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }}
    };

    private void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        // Purchase retrieved from BillingClient#queryPurchasesAsync or your PurchasesUpdatedListener.

        // Verify the purchase.
        // Ensure entitlement was not already granted for this purchaseToken.
        // Grant entitlement to the user.
//        billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, listener);



        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {

            Log.e(TAG, "handlePurchase: "+purchase.getPurchaseState() );






            ConsumeParams consumeParams =
                    ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();




            ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult billingResult, String purchaseToken) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        // Handle the success of the consume operation.
                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Consume: Purchase Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConsumeResponse: "+billingResult.getResponseCode());

                        String productId = currentPurchase.getSkus().toString(); // Get the product ID

                        coinsToBeAdded = 0L;

                        if (productId.equals("buy1000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 1000L;
                        } else if (productId.equals("buy5000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 5000L;

                        } else if (productId.equals("buy10000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 10000L;

                        } else if (productId.equals("buy20000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 20000L;
                        } else if (productId.equals("buy50000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 50000L;
                        } else if (productId.equals("buy100000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 100000L;
                        } else if (productId.equals("buy10000000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 10000000L;
                        } else if (productId.equals("buy10000000000")) {
                            coinsToBeAdded = 10000000000L;
                        }


                        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                                if (document.exists()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Coins: " + document.getLong("ytvfcoins"));
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Coins to be added: " + coinsToBeAdded);
                                    Long ytvfcoins = document.getLong("ytvfcoins");
                                    if (ytvfcoins != null) {
                                        Long newCoins = ytvfcoins + coinsToBeAdded;
                                        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                                        user.put("ytvfcoins", newCoins);
                                        docRef.update(user);
                                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Coins Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                                        user.put("ytvfcoins", coinsToBeAdded);
                                        docRef.update(user);
                                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Coins Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Some error occurred, please contact us.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                            }
                        });




                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Purchase Failed!"+billingResult.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConsumeResponse: "+billingResult.getResponseCode() );
                    }
                }
            };








            // Acknowledge purchase and grant the item to the user
            billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, listener);










            if (!verifyValidSignature(purchase.getOriginalJson(), purchase.getSignature())) {
                // Invalid purchase
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Invalid Purchase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
        else if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
            // Here you can confirm to the user that the pending
            // transaction has been completed.
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5959);
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        }
        else if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE){
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Unspecified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5959);
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }

        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                    AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                            .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                            .build();

            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Purchase Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


//            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
//                currentPurchase = purchase;
//                handlePurchase(purchase);
//            }
            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5959);
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Thanks For Purchase")
                    .setMessage("Your purchase was successful! Your coins will be added to your account shortly.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Continue with delete operation
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_upload_done)
                    .show();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Already Purchased", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5959);
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }


    }

    AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private boolean verifyValidSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
        try {
            String base64Key = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn27b96Bi5kQ8+CXXZZbQFwVa7KsHAs9KB76DF/jfcobmqgEZIyE3UMmh4XMsVPaS8Vxffy93RP64amZl5QM0hr8IbL3jmWYTNdpCOLtqvkVgC8qsz0vNG06RUHin2X/DnvimvCq9CzFMTy3/XfsBhxd+sIqUQxWH093Y+BNcr4gpHb+GcpSTXvImU+N7g0eCyYToVc/yiIxryBnJJw7Cpd8xOIZhPDm252YxQ+dOKqPhswLVzD9NRRkso4+hhADsLMVnUDyeL8eYCbVLaz+288JIFBgC7Skl9btxt+ssAYfvwbB5K9JnbgpTNgof3q/J58wr8qMbsfphq1lr9UUffQIDAQAB";
            return Verify.verifyPurchase(base64Key, signedData, signature);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Got an exception trying to validate a purchase: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void purchaseCoinsListener(String productId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting billing client connection...");
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Billing client setup finished successfully");
                    QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                            .setProductList(
                                    ImmutableList.of(
                                            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                                    .setProductId(productId)
                                                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                                    .build()
                                    )
                            )
                            .build();

                    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
                            queryProductDetailsParams,
                            new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && productDetailsList != null) {
                                        if (!productDetailsList.isEmpty()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Product details query finished successfully");
                                            for (ProductDetails productDetails : productDetailsList) {
                                                ImmutableList productDetailsParamsList =
                                                        ImmutableList.of(
                                                                BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                                                                        .setProductDetails(productDetails)
                                                                        .build()
                                                        );
                                                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                                                        .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
                                                        .build();

                                                Log.d(TAG, "Product ID: " + productDetails.getProductId());
                                                // Launch the billing flow
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Launching billing flow...");
                                                billingResult175 = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(PurchaseCoins.this, billingFlowParams);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Billing flow response code: " + billingResult175.getResponseCode());
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            // Product ID doesn't exist in Google Play Console, show an error message
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Product ID doesn't exist"+productId);
                                            Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Product ID doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        // Handle the error
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Product details query failed with response code: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                                        Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Product details query failed with response code: " + billingResult.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Billing client setup failed with response code: " + billingResult.getResponseCode());
                    Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Billing client setup failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.e(TAG, "Billing service disconnected");
                Toast.makeText(PurchaseCoins.this, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



}

I also tried changin placing of consumeAsync. But no luck.

The code snippet you're sharing is quite big, it would help if you could isolate from where your problem is originating and if you could recude the amount of code you're sharing.

Yes, I have left the code which is related to this only. Please let me know if you know what's the issue here. Thanks in advance.

DId you find out what is the Error 6?
